# Proving Gauss' polynomial theorem (Rational Root Test)

Tags: number-theory, linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x], P(x) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_j x^j, a_n \neq 0$ and $a_0 \neq 0$; if $p/q$ is a root of P (with p and q coprimes) then $p|a_0$ and $q|a_n$

I've managed to prove the first part ($p|a_0$) and I suppose I'm not far from proving the second, though I'd really like some feedback since I'm just starting with making proofs of my own.

Proof:

$P(x) = a_n(x-p/q)\displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=2}^n (x-r_j)$, with $r_j$ being the other n-1 roots of P(x).

It follows that $a_0 = a_n(-p/q)\displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=2}^n (-r_j)$

Then, $-p/q|a_0$ and obviously $p/q|a_0$. Rephrasing, $a_0 = l\frac{p}{q} = \frac{l}{q} p$ with $l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This implies $p|a_0$ if $l/q \in \mathbb{Z}$, but this is trivial since $q|lp$ and q and p are coprimes, so $q|l$.

Therefore, $p|a_0$.

As for the second part, we want to see that $q_i|a_n \forall i \leq n$.

We define $d$ as the least common multiple of $\{q_1, q_2,...,q_n\}$. Then, $q_i|a_n \forall i \leq n \iff d|a_n$.

Also, it follows that $d|\displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=1}^n q_j$, so we want to see that $a_n = l \displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=1}^n q_j$ with $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Here's where I have my doubts with the proof as I have no way to show that l is indeed an integer.

Rearranging the previously given equation for $a_0$:

$a_n = a_0 \displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{-q_j}{p_j}$

Using the previous reasoning, as $p_i|a_0 \forall i \leq n$, then $a_0 = k \displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=1}^n p_j$.

Replacing $a_0$:

$a_n = k \displaystyle\prod\limits_{j=1}^n -q_j$, which is equivalent to $q|a_n$ as shown earlier.

Comment: The proof that $p|a_0$ isn't complete since it assumes without justification that $a_n\ \prod_{j=2}^n(-r_j)\in \mathbb Z$. But one can prove $p|a_0$ the same way as in my answer - see my comment to Mariano.

Comment: I hadn't seen this attributed to Gauss — it's often called the "rational root test".

Comment: @DylanMoreland: Over the last few years I've noticed that a handful of theorems have alternative names here in Latin America (not just my professors, but books, and even Wikipedia, offer this alternative names). This is one example. The intermediate value theorem is called Bolzano's theorem, the rank-nullity theorem is called the 'dimension theorem' and this corollary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary is called Barrow's rule, just to name a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\displaystyle\ \ 0 = q^n P(\frac{p}q) = a_n\ p^n + \color{#c00}q\,  (\overbrace{\!\cdots^{\phantom :\!}}^{\!\large \in\, \Bbb Z}\!)\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}q\mid a_n\,p^n\ \!\overset{(q,\,p)\,=\,1}\Longrightarrow\! q\mid a_n\ $ by Euclid's Lemma.

**Note** $ $  This result is usually called RRT = [Rational Root Test / Theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) not Gauss' polynomial theorem. It is special case of [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29) for polynomials, i.e.  if $\,\alpha\,$ is an algebraic number with [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29) minimal polynomial $\, f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]\,$ and if $\, g(\alpha) = 0\,$ for $\, g(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]\,$ then $\,f\mid g\,$ in $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ hence $\,f\mid g\,$ in $\,\mathbb Z[x]\,$ by Gauss. So the leading coefficient of $\,f\,$ divides the leading coefficient of $\,g,\,$ and ditto for the constant coefficients. RRT is just the special case when $\,f\,$ has degree $= 1.\,$ Indeed $\ \alpha = p/q\in \mathbb Q\,$ with $\,(p,q)=1\,$ has primitive minimal polynomial $\, f(x) = q\,x - p\,$. Therefore if $\,g(\alpha) = 0\,$ above $\Rightarrow (q\,x-p)\,|\,g\ \ in\ \ \mathbb Z[x]\,$ thus $\,q\,|\,g_n,\ p\,|\,g_0\,\ {\rm in}\,\ \mathbb Z,\,$ which is precisely RRT.

Comment: Great answer! It was really that simple. I'll keep this open for a little while to see if someone can spot where I went wrong with my proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to prove the first part, just apply it to the polynomial $t^n P(t^{-1})$.

Comment: (This is of course what's hidden in Bill's hint)

Comment: Yes, either implication is a consequence of the other by reversing the polynomial. But usually the opposite direction is clear once one see the direction I gave. Sometimes I post it symmetrically to make this clear: $ 0 = a_n p^n + pq (\cdots) + a_0 q^n$ implies $ p|a_0, q|a_n$.

Comment: Remark that this is known as the [reciprocal (or reversed) polynomial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2369151/242)