# $r^3-7r+1=0$ why $r$ cannot be rational

Tags: number-theory

In the following equation:

$r^3-7r+1=0$

why $r$ cannot be rational?

---

So far my considerations are the following.

Suppose $r$ is rational. Thus it can be presented in the form $r=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers and co-prime, $q\neq0$.

$\frac{p^3}{q^3}-7\frac pq+1=0 | \times q^3 \iff p^3 - 7pq^2 + q^3 = 0 \iff p^3 + q^3 = 7pq^2$.

But at this level I got stuck in finding the contradiction.
Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, by the Rational Root Test, any rational solution of the equation must be one of $\pm 1$, but neither of those are solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us rearrange your equation in a different way.

First, $p^3=7pq^2-q^3=q(7pq-q^2)$.  Now, since the right hand side is a multiple of $q$, we have $q|p^3$, but also $p$ and $q$ are (by assumption) relatively prime.  Therefore, if there were a solution, $q=\pm 1$.

Now apply similar reasoning to $q^3=7pq^2-p^3=p(7q^2-p^2)$.

This gives you a short list of candidates for $p$ and $q$, hence for $r$.  Do any of them work?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Therefore based on the assumption only r = 1 and r = -1 solutions are available. But these solutions are not valid, thus we have a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Yes.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin fyi: the above proof is exactly a special case of the [proof of the Rational Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8721/242) You may as well do the general proof since it is no more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

It is already naturally imposed that $q \neq 0$. Note that $p \neq 0$; if otherwise then $0 = 1$. Note that $p^{3}+q^{3} = 7pq^{2}$ implies that $q$ divides $p^{3}$. If $q = \pm 1$, then $p^{3} \pm 1 = 7p$, so $p$ divides $\pm 1$, hence $p=\pm 1$, but then $0, 2= \pm 7$, a contradiction. So suppose $p, q \neq \pm 1$. Still it holds that $q$ divides $p^{3}$, which is again impossible as $p,q$ were coprime.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $r^3-7r+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
In particular it does not have any rational root.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{p^{3} + q^{3} = 7pq^{2}\,,\qquad\mbox{LHS} = p^{3} + q^{3}\,,\quad\mbox{RHS} = 7pq^{2}}$.

\begin{align}
\pars{p\ odd,q\ odd} & \implies \pars{\mbox{LHS},\mbox{RHS}} = \pars{even,odd}
\\[1mm]
\pars{p\ odd,q\ even} & \implies \pars{\mbox{LHS},\mbox{RHS}} = \pars{odd,even}
\\[1mm]
\pars{p\ even,q\ odd} & \implies \pars{\mbox{LHS},\mbox{RHS}} = \pars{odd,even}
\\[1mm]\require{cancel}
\cancel{\pars{p\ even,q\ even}} & \implies \cancel{\pars{\mbox{LHS},\mbox{RHS}}} = \cancel{\pars{even,even}}:\ p\ \mbox{and}\ q\ \mbox{have common factors.}
\end{align}

Comment: Only `(p even, q  even)` creates a contradiction. What about the other 3 cases?

Comment: The other three are not possible cases unless $p = q = 0$ which, of course, is not possible too.

Comment: Got it now :). The first 3 cases are contradictions too, since both sides of equation must have the same parity. Excellent proof, thank you!

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin You're welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Essentially the same as Jack's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (another way):

All rational solutions of the equation must satisfy:
$q$ divides the leading coefficient (in this case $1$)
and $p$ divides the constant term (in this case $1$).

$p\over q$ must be in lowest terms.

You have a handful of cases to check.

Answer (score 0):

Direct followed from your attempt.

As $$p^3+q^3=7pq^2$$
$$q^3=p(7q^2-p^2)$$
Seen that $7q^2-p^2\in\mathbb Z$, so $p$ must be a factor of $q^3$, implies that $p$ and $q$ have some factors are same, which already contradicts the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are co-prime if $p\neq\pm 1$.

It is easy to check that $p$ is not $1$ by $vice\ versa$ on $q$. (If so then $q=\pm 1\Rightarrow r=\pm 1$, also a contradiction.)